# how to write .html with .css to custom color text

Tags: jquery, css

How could I incorporate `.css("color" "#fff");` with the *below*:

```
$('.exchange_text').html('Image Received').fadeIn();
```

I would like to have my `.html` text to be a different color, in this line only; so inline.

Comment: Why does the style need to be applied inline? If you can't attach the #fff to the `.exchange_text` class, you could add another class i.e. `.received` and apply the colour to that in your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either apply the color to `exchange_text`

```
$('.exchange_text').css("color", "#fff").html('Image Received').fadeIn();
```

Or use a span and color it

```
$('.exchange_text').html('<span style="color: #fff">Image Received</span>').fadeIn();
```